# Zend plugins not installing properly in my localhost?

Tags: php, joomla

Zend plugins not installing in my localhost.Is this issue related to php.ini or apache.

please help.

Comment: You need to give more information. What plugins are you trying to use? What code are you using to install the plugins?

Comment: I am using joomla to install the zend plugins(i.e in jomsocial).But there is no issue with the joomla pack and the zend plugins.But I think the issue might be in somewhere settings in php.ini.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have fixed the issue and the issue is related to max_execution_time in php.ini
I just increased the execution time and it works fine.

Ex : max_execution_time = 300